# Athena: is datatype `struct<tag1:string,tag2:string>` equivalent to `map<string,string>`?

Tags: amazon-athena

My dataflow is: `json -> parquet -> Athena`, but I'm having a problem with the nested key-value field `tags`.

The JSON file is

```
[{"myid":1,"name":"foo","tags":{"tag1":"a","tag2":"b"}},
 {"myid":2,"name":"bar","tags":{"tag1":"c","tag2":"d"}}
]
```

The Athena table is

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dbname.tablename (
  `myid` int,
  `name` string,
  `tags` STRUCT < tag1 : string, tag2 : string >
)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 's3://path/to/folder'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  "parquet.compress"="SNAPPY"
);
```

and all is good by testing with `select * from dbname.tablename`.

However, if I replace the `STRUCT` with a `tags MAP < string, string >`, the select query throws an exception

```
HIVE_CANNOT_OPEN_SPLIT:
Error opening Hive split s3://path/file.snappy.parquet (offset=0, length=992):
Expected MAP column 'tags.entry' entry to have two fields, but has 1 fields
```

My end goal is to import the json without needing to explicitly write out the keys in the `STRUCT` of the `create table`. Any pointers?

Update: The conversion from json to parquet is done as follows on a spark server (with databricks.com)

```
df_json = spark.read.json("/FileStore/tables/file.json")
df_json.write.parquet("/FileStore/file.parquet")
```

Comment: `Is "struct<tag1:string,tag2:string>" equivalent to "map<string,string>"?` -- it's not. The two types are handled quite differently in Presto / Athena and file formats (eg Parquet or ORC).

Comment: How do you convert json to partquet? If you want to change underlying data structure you need to change it during conversion

Comment: @shuvalov I simply do a `df=spark.read.json("file.json")` followed by `df.write.parquet("file.pq")`

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen How does map look like in json as opposed to struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map and struct looks the same in json, but as mentioned in the comments, map and struct storage are not the same in parquet. In Athena you could not perform implicit conversion of underlying data so you have two options: explicitly convert data during conversion in Spark, or convert data in Athena using CTAS.

### Convert Struct to Map in Spark

By default Spark transform json map into struct:

```
val jsonStr = """
[{"myid":1,"name":"foo","tags":{"tag1":"a","tag2":"b"}},
 {"myid":2,"name":"bar","tags":{"tag1":"c","tag2":"d"}}
]
"""

val df_json = spark.read.json(Seq(jsonStr).toDS.rdd)
df_json.write.parquet(path)
val df_parquet = spark.read.parquet(path)
df_parquet.printSchema
df_parquet.show

root
 |-- myid: long (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tags: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tag1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tag2: string (nullable = true)
+----+----+-----+
|myid|name| tags|
+----+----+-----+
|   1| foo|[a,b]|
|   2| bar|[c,d]|
+----+----+-----+
```

One need to convert `tags` struct explicitly to map:

```
df_json
    .select($"myid", $"name", map(
        lit("tag1"), $"tags.tag1",
        lit("tag2"), $"tags.tag2"
    ) as "tags")
    .write.parquet(path)
val df_parquet = spark.read.parquet(path)
df_parquet.printSchema
df_parquet.show

root
 |-- myid: long (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tags: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
+----+----+-------------------------+
|myid|name|tags                     |
+----+----+-------------------------+
|1   |foo |Map(tag1 -> a, tag2 -> b)|
|2   |bar |Map(tag1 -> c, tag2 -> d)|
+----+----+-------------------------+
```

### Convert Struct to Map using CTAS

In Athena you could not modify existing table but you could create new one with CTAS expression (Create Table As Select):

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temptable (
         `myid` int,
         `name` string,
         `tags` STRUCT < tag1 : string,
         tag2 : string > 
) STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION 's3://xxx' TBLPROPERTIES ( "parquet.compress"="SNAPPY" );

CREATE table temptable2 AS
SELECT myid,
         name,
         MAP(ARRAY['tag1', 'tag2'],ARRAY[tags.tag1, tags.tag2]) AS tags
FROM temptable;
```

`temptable2` now looks like:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `temptable2`(
  `myid` int COMMENT '', 
  `name` string COMMENT '', 
  `tags` map<varchar(4),string> COMMENT '')
```